# Connect Java rest API to JIra

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I want to connect Java with JIRA trial account. I tested this code:

```
public class JiraImpl
{
    private static URI JIRA_URL = URI.create("https://sonoratest.atlassian.net");
    private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME = "sonoratestw@gmail.com";
    private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "sonpass";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
        try
        {
            AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
            JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(JIRA_URL, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD);

            Iterable<BasicProject> allProjects = restClient.getProjectClient().getAllProjects().claim();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run it nothing happens. Wahat is the proper way to get data from JIRA using REST API?

**Update.** I also tried this:

```
private static URI JIRA_URL = URI.create("https://sonoratest.atlassian.net/rest/auth/1/session");
```

I get

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(404), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=404, errors={}, errorMessages=[]}]}
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:63)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.DelegatingPromise.get(DelegatingPromise.java:102)
    at com.jira.impl.JiraImpl.main(JiraImpl.java:23)
Caused by: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(404), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=404, errors={}, errorMessages=[]}]}
```

Comment: Did you get an error?

Comment: Well, this code wouldn't actually produce any output so unless you're getting an error I don't see the problem

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: Your post is a bit unclear, but I assume that you got the 404 when you used this URL "https://sonoratest.atlassian.net/rest/auth/1/session". 404 means "not found", which makes sense, because JRJC will append to that URL. What error do you get when you use  "https://sonoratest.atlassian.net"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try getting an issue first, since that is so basic.

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClient;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory;
import com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promise;

public class JRC
{
    public Issue getIssue(String issueKey) throws Exception
    {
        final URI jiraServerUri = new URI("https://jira-domain");
        final JiraRestClient restClient = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory().createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, "user@domain.com", "password");
        Promise issuePromise = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue(issueKey);
        return Optional.ofNullable((Issue) issuePromise.claim()).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("No such issue"));
    }

}
```

You can also take a look at this code to get a fully working sample:

https://github.com/somaiah/jrjc

Comment: I tried your code, but its throwing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException. What I could be doing wrong ?

Comment: Your code needs an SSL cert to connect to your jira server. Guessing it's on https. The easiest way to see if the code itself works is to try to connect to your jira server via http, instead of https (if it's set up for that). Otherwise you'll need to add the cert to your jira server into your Java keystore

Comment: @SomaiahKumbera I have tried with the same approach but I am getting ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError``` for createWithBasicHttpAuthentication. I have added details in gist https://gist.github.com/ashishranjanJN/8a08d2815433580ced15f0b0caf24b87 . Let me know what am I missing.